# Polling vs KVO/NSNotification/Delegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c-blocks

I have a tool on the mac which has data processing interface, web interface and UI. These three interfaces run on three different serial (async) dispatch_queues.(UI runs on main queue)

My data processing interface needs to Stop when the web interface receives the command, Stop. The data processing dispatch_block does not have any dependencies except it needs to listen to Stop command from the web interface.

I am confused about how should I design the data block, so that, I don't have to poll web interface to check if it received the Stop command. 
The stack for my data block is quite deep(lot of function calls) and I don't want to check in the each function if Stop has been called. 
The objective is to stop as soon as possible when I receive the *Stop* command.

I can't rely on the `isCancelled` method of `NSOperationBlock` as my data block is always running until it receives Stop.

My aim here is not how to design the interfaces in better manner but to quickly exit data block when I receive the *Stop* command.

I do know this is an age old problem of how to avoid checking a variable all the time. Was just wondering if there is something which could be done.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can’t just kill the data processing block. That would lead to memory leaks and unstable state. The `isCancelled` approach of NSNSOperation is the best way to go. The Stop command should set a variable that is local to the data processing block and from within the block you check that variable at convenient places and clean up and exit when its set.